# From Django 1.4 to Django 2.1.5 : custom field to_python() not called anymore

Tags: python, django

I am migrating an application from python 2/Django 1.4 to python 3/Django 2.1.5. I have a strange behaviour with a custom JSON field :

```
class JSONField(models.TextField):
    """JSONField is a generic textfield that neatly serializes/unserializes
JSON objects seamlessly. Main thingy must be a dict object."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'default' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['default'] = '{}'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        """Convert our string value to JSON after we load it from the DB"""
        if not value:
            return {}
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            res = loads(value)
            assert isinstance(res, dict)
            return res
        else:
            return value

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        """Convert our JSON object to a string before we save"""
        if not value:
            return super(JSONField, self).get_db_prep_save("", connection=connection)
        else:
            return super(JSONField, self).get_db_prep_save(dumps(value), connection=connection)
```

With Django 1.4, JSONField.to_python() is called when I read an object from database, but not with Django 2.1.5 : do you know why ?

Comment: Did you really just upgrade 10 major versions? Did you read the release notes for each version as you upgraded?

Comment: I read them. I made a lot of modifications accordingly. But for custom fields it seems I missed something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, `to_python` is called whenever you are saving an instance of object to DB. And this function is used to convert the value from given type to desired type. From method's documentation:

> Convert the input value into the expected Python data type, raising
>           django.core.exceptions.ValidationError if the data can't be converted.
>           Return the converted value. Subclasses should override this.

For example in `TextField`, the `to_python` function looks like this:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, str) or value is None:
        return value
    return str(value)
```

Here, it converts a value to string regardless its previous type. Meaning, you can pass an integer value though `TextField`, but it will be converted to String when its being saved to DB.

Finally, if you want to use JSONField, then for Postgresql, consider using [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) provided by django. If you are using MySQL, then you can look into [django-mysql's](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql) [JSONField](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html).

Comment: to_python is not called when object is saved, but when it is read from db and deserialzed into a python object. If I put a print into to_python : I can see it with Django 1.4 but not with Django 2.1.5 : I need to understand why.

Comment: @Eric I don't know what the logic was in django 1.4, but in django 2.1 it happens the way described in the answer. You can check the method's documentation yourself at here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L560

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.4, when querying the database, when values are set to model objects attributes, to_python() is call everytime :

```
class Creator(object):
    """
    A placeholder class that provides a way to set the attribute on the model.
    """
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            raise AttributeError('Can only be accessed via an instance.')
        return obj.__dict__[self.field.name]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = self.field.to_python(value)
```

But this is not the case anymore for Django 2.1.5 : `to_python()` is called mainly during form validation ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects ). To get value modified on database querying, one should now override `from_db_value()`
This method is added to the converters list which is applied on every query :

In field.py :

```
def get_db_converters(self, connection):
    if hasattr(self, 'from_db_value'):
        return [self.from_db_value]
    return []
```

In models/query.py :

```
if converters:
    query = compiler.apply_converters(query, converters)
```

In sql/compiler.py :

```
def apply_converters(self, rows, converters):
    connection = self.connection
    converters = list(converters.items())
    for row in map(list, rows):
        for pos, (convs, expression) in converters:
            value = row[pos]
            for converter in convs:
                value = converter(value, expression, connection)
            row[pos] = value
        yield row
```